# Creating an array during run-time and passing it to a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, runtime

I'm getting some input from the user in the main() function and create an array accordingly. Because of the nature of the location of this array it is not visible to other functions and I need to pass it to a few other functions for processing.

Is there any way to do this without allocating memory for it and passing a pointer to that allocated memory?
flight is structure typedef.

```
int main()
{
    do{ // Read # of flights from user
        printf("Enter max number of flights to read in from file\n");
        printf("--> ");
        fflush(stdin);
    } while(!(scanf("%d",&num_of_flights)));

    flight database[num_of_flights];      // Create database for flights
```

Comment: Why can you not write some code?

Comment: Pass the array as it is? If you create it in the `main` function, it should stay in scope until the program exits.

Comment: @EdHeal - added the beginning of main

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Pass it as C allows passing arrays, as a pointer. I think that if it is created inside main that's the scope of the array so I need to use malloc() and pass a pointer?

Comment: Arrays decays to pointers. So if you pass an array to a function, it will be passed as a pointer.

Comment: Note that calling `fflush` on `stdin` is technically undefined behavior. Some environments have it defined as an extension of the specification, but it's not to be considered good thing to do.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Yes, I'm aware of that. I am asking about the run-time created array which is 'scoped' to the main() function. Can I pass it as is to other functions?

Comment: Yes, it's like any other array.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - And if the array was created dynamically in another function and returned would that be OK too? Is main() special in that form that it stays "alive" for as long as the program runs and that's why the memory location for the array is kept?

Comment: "Can I pass it as is to other functions? " -- Yes, of course, why not? "Is main() special" -- no, every function is "alive" until it returns -- what other possibilities are there? main is alive for as long as the program runs because the program runs until main returns (unless you create subprocesses or threads).

Comment: @JimBalter - just these two possibilities if the variable is defined internal to the function and not static. Thanks.

Comment: I meant what other possibility is there to functions being "alive" until they return. Until a function returns, it is valid to reference its locals; after it returns, referencing them is undefined behavior.

Comment: If you allocate memory (with e.g. `malloc`) in another function and return a pointer to that memory, that pointer is valid until you `free` the memory. And since the lifetime of the program is the `main` function (or until you `exit`) it's logical that variables defined at the top-level scope in `main` will have the same lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

In C you can allocate memory during runtime in such way

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int *array, int array_size){
  for(int i = 0;  i < array_size; ++i){
    printf("%d ", *(array + i));
  }
}
int main(){
  int *array;
  int array_size;
  scanf("%d", &array_size);
  array = malloc(sizeof(int) * array_size);
  // Fill array with ints
  for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
    *(array + i) = i;
  }

  print_array(array, array_size);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for your contribution. Note, however, that the question is not about how to allocate memory, and in fact is about alternatives to doing so. BTW, `array[i]` is equivalent to but preferable to `*(array + i)`.

Answer (score 0):

From the C standard, 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects:

> The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during
>   which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists,
>   has a constant address) and retains its last-stored value
>   throughout its lifetime....
>   An object whose identiﬁer is declared with no linkage and without the
>   storage-class speciﬁer static has automatic storage duration...
>   For such an object that does not have a variable length array type,
>   its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is
>   associated until execution of that block ends in any way.

So, the lifetime of `database` extends until the execution of its enclosing block ends. That block is the body of `main`, so it is alive until `main` returns or the program exits. Therefore, you can simply pass `database` to other functions, or even store its address in a global that is accessed by other functions ... there is no need to allocate space and copy it.

BTW, you should be aware that by defining `database[num_of_flights]`, where `num_of_flights` is not a constant, you are using a relatively recent feature of C -- variable length arrays (VLA's) -- and that some prominent C compilers (cough, Visual Studio, cough) do not support them.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how you might use malloc on a struct and then use the malloc'd item as a parameter to other functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct fl {
    int distance;
    char aeroplane[30];
    char startgeo[2];
};
typedef struct fl flight;

void show_flight_data(flight d) {
    printf("distance %d aeroplane %s",d.distance, d.aeroplane);
}

int main()
{
    int num_of_flights;
    flight *database;

    do{ // Read # of flights from user
        printf("Enter max number of flights to read in from file\n");
        printf("--> ");
        fflush(stdin);
    } while(!(scanf("%d",&num_of_flights)));

    database=(flight *)malloc(sizeof(flight) * num_of_flights);
    database[0].distance = 100;
    database[1].distance = 200;
    strcpy(database[0].aeroplane,  "777");
    strcpy(database[1].aeroplane,  "Airbus");
    show_flight_data(database[0]);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: The question is not about how to allocate memory, but rather about how to avoid doing so.

Comment: ok thanks, I read the question as "how can I avoid preallocation of memory?"  The question as interpreted by the current thread of comments shows, seems to make little sense!